# Controlling GTK selection

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk, selection, gnome

I'm using a custom on-screen keyboard to fill out a GTKEntry in GTK 2. My issue is arises in that after a button press, I want to automatically return selection to the entry box in order to display the nice flashing cursor. Does there exist a function I can call to control this selection ? Thank you for weighing in on what may be considered an outdated question

edit: [gtk-widget-grab-focus](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-grab-focus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that on-screen keyboard button is Gtk.Button, combine these two

```
void on_clicked (GtkButton *button, gpointer data)
{
gtk_entry_buffer_insert_text (buffer,\
                             gtk_entry_buffer_get_length (buffer) + 1,\
                             "blablablah",\ 
                             -1)
gtk_entry_grab_focus (entry)
gtk_editable_set_position (GTK_EDITABLE (entry), -1)
}
```